# NVIDIA ShadowPlay - how enable/disable via console

Tags: windows, nvidia-graphics-card

NVIDIA ShadowPlay - how enable/disable via command line console or programmatically via script/bat/cpp ?

Comment: Are you asking how to programmatically start/stop recording, or how to enable/disable the shadowplay feature?

Comment: I think you could be asking for either based on the language you've used in your question. I asked for clarification because you could either "enable shadowplay [recording]" or "enable shadowplay [feature]". Improving the choice of words in the question will help others searching for this too.

Comment: @ilw - You need to tell us which one you want to enable through a command prompt.  We are asking for clarification because, in its current form, your question is not clear.

Comment: Ramhound - this is your problem, my question clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

See the article
[[Guide] Shadowplay Mods](https://linustechtips.com/main/topic/331710-guide-shadowplay-mods/),
and especially the section "MANAGING SHADOWPLAY" for the requested information.

To disable NVIDIA ShadowPlay, run the following command as administrator:

```
C:\Windows\system32\rundll32.exe C:\Windows\system32\nvspcap64.dll,ShadowPlayDisable
```

To turn it back on, run:

```
C:\Windows\system32\rundll32.exe C:\Windows\system32\nvspcap64.dll,ShadowPlayEnable
```

EDIT: This no longer works (2019). The Geforce Experience program is left
as the only tool for this.

If you wish to disable system services, the
`NvContainerLocalSystem` and `NvContainerNetworkService` services are both
used for using NVIDIA GameStream and at least one of them is responsible
for recording. In addition, the services `nvsphelper64.exe`/`nvsphelper.exe`
(64- and 32-bit versions) listen for the hotkey that opens the
GeForce Experience overlay, by default 
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>.

For stopping/starting system services, you could use these commands
run as Administrator:

```
sc stop NvContainerLocalSystem
sc stop NvContainerNetworkService

sc start NvContainerLocalSystem
sc start NvContainerNetworkService
```

Comment: Thanks for update ) one thing - NvContainerLocalSystem enough, and you can add permission for service for all via process hacker and administrator is not needed.